# help with understanding vector functions.

Tags: calculus

I was reading a calculus book in which there was a definition of vector function as: A function which assigns to every real number in the domain of a vector function, a vector in V(3). But i don't know what V(3) means. Please help.

Comment: It means a three dimensional vector.

Comment: @JohnDouma So it means a vector is assigned in three dimensional vector?

Comment: That depends on the domain. A vector valued function can be from vectors  to vectors or from numbers to vectors. You can even have a function from vectors of a different size to 3D vectors.

Answer (score 1):

That is pretty non-standard notation, but V(3) means 3-dimensional euclidean space. It is the space of tuples (x,y,z).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the definition refers to a function that has as independent variable a real number and has as value a three dimensional vector. I.e. a function: $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$. A function of this type has form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2\\
y_3
\end{bmatrix}
=F(x)=
\begin{bmatrix}
F_1(x)\\
F_2(x)\\
F_3(x)
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
with $F_i:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are real functions.

---

You can think at the vector 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2\\
y_3
\end{bmatrix}$$ 
simply as a point in $3-$dimensional space and a simple example of such a function is a rule that defines the coordinates of a point  $P=(x,y,z)$ in such a way that:
$$
x=1+2t \qquad y=2-t \qquad z=1+t
$$
where $t$ is a real number. All the points given by this function stay on a stright line.

Comment: Sorry I am a high school student and i don't know much about Linear Algebra.

Comment: Well. You can think to a function that assign to each real number a point in the $3-$dimensional space. I add something to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's the 3D Euclidean space. The space we live in and are used to.

A good example is the temperature of each point in the room, let's represent this function with  T(x,y,z). For each coordinate (x,y,z) the function T(x,y,z) gives you the temperature inside the room.

Comment: @user258250 another more commonly used notation for the $3D$ Euclidean vector space which you've probably seen is $\Bbb R^{3}$.

Comment: @Ben: temperature is not a vector function but a scalar function.

Comment: @Ben Yes and so R^2 means a 2-D Euclidean space.